# How many sequences of a length = n

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many sequences of a length = n and values of the set {1...n} we can get if each number from 1 to k occur to them.

I know that it will be at least k!

Comment: Sequences - does the order matter? Can we choose the same element twice? Is $k \le n$?

Comment: In the sequences the order is important, I think. 
Damn, k! is wrong idea? It's my begining point.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are allowing repetition.  Hint:  how many sequences are there without the restriction that you use all the numbers $[1,k]?$  How many sequences are missing one specific number out of $[1,k]?$  You have counted the ones that are missing two numbers out of $[1,k]$ twice, so use inclusion-exclusion to finish up.

Comment: Ok, so the number of all sequences is $$ n^{n} $$
How to use inclusion-exclusion? I have no idea how to count it.

Comment: Right, and the number of sequences missing a given one of $[1,k]$ is $(n-1)^n$, so you might think the number missing any one of $[1,k]$ is $k(n-1)^n$ and the number with all of $[1,k]$ is $n^n-k(n-1)^n$.  As I said, that subtracts all the ones missing two different numbers of $[1,k]$ twice, so you need to add them back in once.  Then think about how many times you have counted the ones missing three.